# Inserting results of two sums together to a table

Tags: sql, sum

From my previous question, I've managed to get things to work using the Microsoft SQL Server and importing the excel file to a new database. Now, my question is dealing with writing the right sql commands. I'm trying to sum up the same column of a table twice using different criteria, and then input those numbers to a different table. I know how to insert a sum to a table, but I wonder how I can insert two sums that came from the same column simultaneously (since each time I insert, a new row is created) to the same row of a table.

Additional question: what is the way I should organize my results are dependent on values from a third table? Sample data as follows.

Some sample data:

```
DeptID      Department
15          Eng
16          Eng
17          Mkt
18          Mkt


| Person |    DeptID  | Type | Number  | 
+--------+------------+------+---------+
|   A    |     15     |  p1  |   1     |
|   B    |     18     |  p2  |   5     |
|   C    |     16     |  p2  |   10    |
|   D    |     17     |  p1  |   7     |
|   E    |     18     |  p1  |   11    |
|   F    |     16     |  p2  |   12    |
```

So the result I should give is as such:

```
| Department | Sum of p1  | Sum of p2 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|     Eng    |     1      |     22    |
|     Mkt    |     18     |     5     |
```

What I've tried is as follows:

```
select sum(Amount) as engsump1 from Sheet1$
where Department = 'Eng' and Type = 'p1'

select sum(Amount) as engsump2 from Sheet1$
where Department = 'Eng' and Type = 'p2'

select sum(Amount) as mktsump1 from Sheet1$
where Department = 'Mkt' and Type = 'p1'

select sum(Amount) as mktsump2 from Sheet1$
where Department = 'Mkt' and Type = 'p2'
```

Run it once and after I see the results, perform the insert into function. I'm just wondering if I can do this two steps in one step.

Comment: Unclear, provide sample data, what you have tried?

Comment: just added sample data. let me know if there's anything else I should add.

Answer (score 1):

To sum the 'number' column in each group, you can use the SUM() function; Just put a case statement inside there, so you can sum the cases when type is p1, and sum the cases when type is p2.

To separate the departments, just use a GROUP BY clause. Try this:

```
SELECT department, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'p1' THEN number ELSE 0 END) AS totalP1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'p2' THEN number ELSE 0 END) AS totalP2
FROM myTable
GROUP BY department;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a06b/1) example.

Comment: thanks! this is really helpful!! ok, a side point, is there a function in sql where I can know if a date (written as DD/MM/YYYY) lands on a certain day of the week (e.g. that 4/13/2015 is a monday)?

Comment: just added a new extension to the question.